# Why need a scala mongodb driver when there is a java mongodb driver?

Tags: scala

scala can use java directly,like jdbc and servlet,so why there is mongodb driver for scala:

```
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/
```

why not use java driver?

and It seems scala mongodb driver use java mongodb driver directly

```
case class MongoClient(private val wrapped: JMongoClient) extends Closeable
```

so why need a new one?Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier and more convenient for Scala folks to call into a Scala library.

This hides the Java interop that has to happen from them and they can use more idiomatic Scala (using the Scala collection library, Scala concurrency primitives, implicit parameters, typesafe mapping into case classes using macro-generated codecs and all that).

The official MongoDB Scala driver may not be the best example for embracing Scala to the fullest, though, there is a quite popular alternative in ReactiveMongo.

Comment: In theory, you may also want to write a pure-Scala library instead of depending on Java code, because then you can compile to non-JVM environments such as Scala Native or Scala JS.

Comment: Or [reactivemongo](http://reactivemongo.org/) (I'm acontributors of) not based on a Java driver (even if as most of Scala lib it ends using some "pieces" of Java ecosystem, except as said for Scala native/js)